# Air AutoUpdate & Windows 7 pin icon

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I've created an Air app for use in work. To make things slightly easier, I pin the icon to taskbar (Windows 7). The app uses the auto-update framework (default), which works fine.

After I update though, the pinned icon becomes a default blank page icon. If I click on this icon, Windows will tell me that it can't find the program. I need to unpin the icon and repin a new one (the icon in the start menu works fine).

Anyone else have this problem and know how to fix it?

I'm using AIR 2.7 (compiling with the Flex 4.1 SDK) and I'm on Windows 7 64 bit if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resurrecting an old question. After digging around with pretty specific questions on Google, I found 2 posts, one in the Adobe forums:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3449244

and the other in the JIRA:

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-24649

It looks like this bug has been open for a while and isn't getting fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to wrap your app inside another app as a module and only update that module. That way only the module SWF would be overwritten, leaving the original app intact.

Comment: that seems a pretty messy workaround for one bug :) - in any case, when the wrapper swf gets updated, the icon would be overwritten there (as the icon is set using the application.xml file, and that's how the auto-update works)

Comment: Like I said, it's a workaround, not a solution ;) I realize that seems overkill for the situation. I don't have Win7 at work so I have no idea how pinned apps react. Also, if you don't plan to update the wrapper (only reason you'd need to if if you switch SDK version or change the icon) it's no big deal. Another advantage of doing it is that the module could be updated without any need to restart the app.